# Calculate and show custom installments with product price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I am trying to adapt this code from shopify to woocommerce using html or php, to calculate with taxes. In my webstore I have installed wordpress, woocommerce and elementor pro.

I need to use the concept from 1,2,3,.. 12 installments "Monthly payment" and I will use for all products, thus I need to find the variables as product.price and product.id on woocommerce.
It is an example:
https://camisetaz.com.br/collections/especiais/products/chug-life?variant=15424306053177

The code is:

```css
.boxParcelas .row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 100% !important;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.boxParcelas img.cartoes {
  height: 22px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.boxParcelas img {
  height: 12px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 996px) {
  .boxParcelas .hideOnMobile {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="boxParcelas" style="border: 1px solid #dadada; padding: 5px; background-color: #fff; margin-bottom: 15px;">
    <div id="clicktrigger" style="margin:0; cursor: pointer; border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada; padding: 5px 5px;">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0">

            <div style="padding:0; width: 75%; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;">
                <img data-img="visa" src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/visa.svg"
                    class="cartoes">
                <img data-img="master" src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/master.svg"
                    class="cartoes">
                <img data-img="american_express"
                    src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/amex.svg" class="cartoes">
                <img data-img="cielo"
                    src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/celo.svg" class="cartoes">
               <img data-img="hiper_card"
                    src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/hipercard.svg" class="cartoes">
               <img data-img="aura"
                    src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/aura.png" class="cartoes">
              <img data-img="discovery"
                    src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/discovery.png" class="cartoes">
            </div>
            <div style="padding:0; width: 25%; text-align: right; padding-top: 3px;">
                <span class="hideOnMobile">Parcelas</span>
                <span style="margin-left: 12px;">
                    <img src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/iconseta.png">
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="boxJuros" style="display: block; font-size: 0.8em; padding: 15px;">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">1x</span> de {{ product.price | money }} sem juros <br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">2x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 2 | times: 1.0451 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">3x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 3 | times: 1.0604 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">4x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 4 | times: 1.0759 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">5x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 5 | times: 1.0915 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">6x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 6 | times: 1.1072 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">7x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 7 | times: 1.1189 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">8x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 8 | times: 1.1345 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">9x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 9 | times: 1.1499 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">10x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 10 | times: 1.1659 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">11x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 11 | times: 1.1819 | money }}<br>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">12x</span> de {{ product.price | divided_by: 12 | times: 1.1979 | money }}<br>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 0px; display: block;  border-top: 1px solid #dadada; padding: 5px;">
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0">
            <div style="padding:0; width: 75%; text-align: left; text-decoration: none;"> 
                <img class="cartoes"
                    src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/boleto.svg">
              <img class="cartoes"
                    src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/mp.png">
              <img class="cartoes"
                    src="https://universidadedropshipping.com/bandeiras_parcelamento/getnet.png">
            </div>
            <div style="padding:0; width: 25%; text-align: right; padding-top: 3px;"> 
                <span>{{ product.price | money }}</span> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```